# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js, line 3

Tags: ember-cli

I'm upgrading my Ember CLI addon from 0.1.9 to 0.2.0, and am hitting this error when running `ember test --server`:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js, line 3

`ember serve` works, and I can visit `/tests` in the browser, but something else seems to have broken the testem/phantom setup.

I've upgraded Phantom, and went through the `ember init` diffs several times, but I must still be missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was I had used ES6 syntax in one of my files in `/addon`. ES6 isn't supported there (yet), so it was throwing this error.

Removing the ES6 (in this case, back ticks) solved the problem.

### Update

Simply `npm install --save ember-cli-babel` in your addon to get Babel support for the files in your `/addon` directory.

Comment: Why is ES6 not supported in /addon? Because it's "vendor" code I guess? I just encountered the same issue.