# Phantomjs 2.0.1 can't find variable define at /assets/test-loader.js

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, acceptance-testing, ember-qunit, ember-testing

At first, I want to say that I faced the exact same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397189/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-define-at-http-localhost7357-assets-test). But the thing is, the answer doesn't fit me, I installed babel, updated it to the latest version and nothing changed. Also, I uninstalled my phantomjs 1.9.8 and installed 2.0.1, I thought that was a great idea, but again, no result. Does anybody know the reason why this can happen?

Comment: Do you use ES6 in addons like in referenced question?

Comment: Daniel, if I say yes, u must keep in mind, that I tried using babel + 1.9.8/2.0.1 phantomjs, but 2.0.1 must support ES6, so I'm not sure that's the case.

Comment: I guess you have to install babel in addon directory? Is this possible? Have you tried that?

Comment: Daniel, I have a lot of addons, really a lot, I don't even index them to search over the code if there is ES6 syntax anywhere, and if I knew exactly, what addon causes that problem, I'm not sure, that manually installing babel will work out during deploy

Comment: Are you saying that your code works in Phantom 1.9.8 but is broken in 2.0.1?

Comment: GJK, no, not at all. My code is broken on both Phantom 1.9.8 and 2.0.1, it works only in Chrome! Also, my teammates encountered the same error, so it doesn't depend on spesific configurations of my VM

Comment: Daniel, u were right, I've finally found the addon, that was using es6 syntax. I didn't install babel into it, just refactored one string in it. Thank you! If u place an answer, I will accept it.
P.S. Even now, I cannot get why PhantomJS 2.0.1 feels bad with es6

Comment: Hey, I've added answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find addon that's using ES6 in your addons and either remove ES6 code from it or install there Babel.